# Java Out of bounds exception with TreeNodes

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, treenode

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //creates tree as linked structure
    int lvl = 0;
    LinkedList<TreeNode> lcaTree = new LinkedList<>();
    TreeNode[] charArray = new TreeNode[lcaTree.size()];
    String[] myStringChars = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P",
                                          "Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        myStringChars[i] = new String(Character.toChars(i+65));
        System.out.println(myStringChars[i]);
        //reads removed value from queue as an Object; needs to be a TreeNode
    }

    // create the Tree as a linked structure from the array myStringChars
    // the Strings are stored using the representation for trees as arrays in the book
    // (e.g. for an element i, the left child is stored in position 2*i + 1, right child is 
    // on position 2*(i + 1). Also specify the level of a TreeNode

    for (int i = 0; i < myStringChars.length; i++){
        TreeNode parent = null;
        if (i == 0){
            parent = new TreeNode<>("A", null);
            parent.setLevel(lvl);
            lvl++;
        }
        else{
            //set level
            if((i == 3)||(i == 7)||(i == 15)){
                lvl++;
            }
            else if (myStringChars[i].toCharArray()[0]%2 == 1){
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get((i/2)-1));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)-1).setRightChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);
            }
       *****else{
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get(i/2));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)).setLeftChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);*****
            }
            lcaTree.add(parent);
        }
    }
    //creates array from tree
    charArray[0] = lcaTree.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length-1; i++){
        if (2*(i+1) < charArray.length){
            charArray[2*(i+1)] = lcaTree.get(i).getRightChild();
        }
        if ((2*i)+1 < charArray.length){
            charArray[(2*i)+1] = lcaTree.get(i).getLeftChild();
        }
    }
    // create a traversal by levels and print as you traverse to check that the creation of the tree has happened correctly

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(charArray[i].getContents());
        if (i==0||(i==2)||(i==6)||(i==14)){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Hi all.  So this is a little exercise I'm doing with TreeNodes and basic Java stuff in general and I've run into an error I could use some fresh eyes helping to identify.

I'm getting an out of bounds exception around the statement that I put asterisks around.  I don't know why i/2 would ever result in an out of bounds condition seeing as how 0/2 is 0 and 26/2 returns 13(min/max i values), neither of which are out of bounds.

Could anyone offer some further insight?  Thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: is `i/2` a integer or a double? eventually use integer operations.

Comment: i was declared as int in the loop

Comment: so it is time for debugging. Good luck!

Comment: Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62550', transport: 'socket'
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
 at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
 at TreeExercise.main(TreeExercise.java:54)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62550', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1


This is what debugging has given me.  What I already know.  I'm wondering if someone else can ID the logic.

Comment: From your example we can't see that `lcTree` is nothing but an empty List.

Comment: please edit your answer and put the stackTrace there.. think about how things are clear for us when you want someone to look at your problem.

Comment: and yes as @jogo said, Debugger is your friend and a great teacher I'd add ;)

Comment: All the stack trace is doing is telling me that it's not satisfying the conditions for being in bound.  That's not telling me what's actually wrong with my logic, which from all appearances looks sound.  Also,  lcaTree is built from the myStringChars array.

Comment: @TimTolbert see the fix bellow. You should have found this error your self and it would have been easy have you at least debugged your application.  Too many people just to quickly raise hand to ask for help, actually sitting with your problem & researchingh for a while helps you learn a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `i=0` iteration you have created your root node in the `if(i==0)` block but you have not added it to `lcaTree`.

On you next iteration `i = 1` in your `else` block `lcaTree.get(0)` will throw `OutOfBounds` because you have nothing on the position 0, your Array is zero length.

So, fix your for loop:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < myStringChars.length; i++){
        TreeNode parent = null;
        if (i == 0){
            parent = new TreeNode<>("A", null);
            parent.setLevel(lvl);
            lvl++;
        }
        else{
            //set level
            if((i == 3)||(i == 7)||(i == 15)){
                lvl++;
            }
            else if (myStringChars[i].toCharArray()[0]%2 == 1){
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get((i/2)-1));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)-1).setRightChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);
            }
            else{
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get(i/2));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)).setLeftChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);
            }
            lcaTree.add(parent); //<--- move out!
        }
    }
```

and put `lcaTree.add(parent);` outside of else condition?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringChars.length; i++){
        TreeNode parent = null;
        if (i == 0){
            parent = new TreeNode<>("A", null);
            parent.setLevel(lvl);
            lvl++;
        }
        else{
            //set level
            if((i == 3)||(i == 7)||(i == 15)){
                lvl++;
            }
            else if (myStringChars[i].toCharArray()[0]%2 == 1){
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get((i/2)-1));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)-1).setRightChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);
            }
            else{
                parent = new TreeNode<>(myStringChars[i], lcaTree.get(i/2));
                lcaTree.get((i/2)).setLeftChild(parent);
                parent.setLevel(lvl);
            }
        }
        lcaTree.add(parent); // <- like so!
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I'm still getting an out of bounds exception on lcaTree.add(parent) for whatever reason.

Apparently I can't add a node to a linked list? I thought the entire point of the linked list was that things could be freely added/removed since linked lists are dynamic structures.